# using watch run 2 commands

Tags: command-line, bash, watch-command

I have to do watch two commands in the same terminal windows. I mean something like

```
watch du -h filename.txt && df -h
```

But its showing only one output.

So what I am thinking is may be its not possible to use watch to run multiple commands on the same window.

If there is any way , Please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

You can quote the commands:

```
watch "du -h filename.txt && df -h"
```

And they'll be executed together.

Comment: Thanks Oli. actually office PC so not daring to do experiments. so posted here for sure solution. Thank you.

Comment: Hey you sure they will work ? because when execute I am getting some permission denied error" df: `/usr/raja/hostctrl/new': Permission denied "

Comment: That seems to be a separate issue. You'd see that issueeven without it being wrapped in watch.

Comment: Be aware this works because those example commands return with _true_. Should the first command return _false_ the second command wouldn't be executed (because of `boolean evaluation shortcut`)

Comment: FTR, my command uses `&&` because the OP uses `&&`.  The combination of commands and their linking is incidental to the answer.

Comment: `watch "du -h filename.txt ; df -h` gets around the problem karatedog mentioned.  Further reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13077241/execute-combine-multiple-linux-commands-in-one-line

Answer (score 33):

If you want to make sure both commands execute, one of the ways is to separate them with `;` instead of `&&`.

```
watch 'du -h filename.txt; df -h'
```

`&&` allows the execution of second command (second operand, to the right of `&&`) only if the first command executed successfully (exit status `0`). If this is intended behaviour, go with `&&`.

Comment: This semicolon form seems best to me as an answer to the original question. If you want to "run two commands", use a semicolon! If you want to "run one command, then maybe another" use && ....

Answer (score 7):

For completeness sake...

```
 watch 'du -h filename.txt || true && df -h'
```

The  '|| true' part causes the first command to evaluate as true even if it fails for some reason. This will allow the next command after the && to execute no matter the output of first. This is most likely unnecessary for the scenario, just showing it to be possible.

Comment: could `|| true &&` be replaced with a single `;`?

Comment: @wotanii yes, you could just use `;`.

Answer (score 1):

For multiple commands to run simultaneously, use single `&` operator between the commands. Like:

```
dothis & dothat
```

To clear any confusion, here's how different operators work:

```
c1 & c2  # Run both commands parallelly
c1 ; c2  # Run both commands one by one
c1 && c2 # Run c2 only if c1 exits successfully
c1 || c2 # Run c2 only if c1 fails
```

Comment: c1 & c2 will not run both commands parallel, if c1 is successful run then only c2 will run.

Comment: Actually running 'c1 & c2' what it does is run c1 in background and run c2.
You can test it out yourself: 
`(exit 1) && echo "Success"` will not print "Success", while `(exti 1) & echo` "Success" will print "Success"

Comment: This gave me some insights that I appreciated, therefore upvoting.